# Concrete5 Stacks & Blocks

Tags: concrete5, concrete5-5.7, concrete

I am working on existing concrete5 website and I don't have sufficient knowledge of concrete database structure.
I am creating api to fetch all the products which are added in "Stacks and Blocks".
I have cID, stID values and fetched the info from stacks table, Can anyone please let me know How to fetch the complete details including image from database.

I tried to make the relation between tables based on cID, stID.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of al please clearify your question by adding more information. What are the products (c5-page or an doctrine entity), what do you mean by "added in Stacks and Blocks" - is this the c5 functionality or is this a table which you named so?

Answer (score -1):

The images are stored in the `application/files` directory although you'll need to retrieve the path from the database to find them. as @1stthomas noted, without more details of the information you are working with, it's difficult to provide any specific advice.

FWIW, the API documentation for concrete5 [can be found here](https://documentation.concrete5.org/api/8.4.3/).